# I want to achieve this onboarding screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[onboarding screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIZCt.png),

I tried this way but can't have it right way.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppStyles.bgColor,
      body: SizedBox(
        width: Get.width,
        height: Get.height,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Gap(100),
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 200,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/one.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              // width: Get.width,
              height: Get.height * 0.45,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: AssetImage("lib/assets/images/blue.png"),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

My screen will be little bit different as I want to show image on top (not as background) then the stacked shape on bottom.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Stack for Background Image And Foreground Blob Image(or create shape with Paint/CustomPaint).
2. Use Stack for Background(Image+blob as a single design) and Text.

I would recommend 2 since its cleaner to get the design file, but its usecase specific.

Comment for more info if not clear.

**You have to use Stack to get the desired UI.**